# doing some ontology enrichment analysis

Tags: bioinformatics, rna-seq

I have my RNA sequencing results output from DeSEQ2 and eager to generate some figures. I try to run the following command, only for it to tell me that the input does not match the required format, when I clearly see that it is not true. Please if anybody knows how to fix this bug, I would kindly appreciate your contribution in comment section further.

```
GO.params.bp <- GSEAGOHyperGParams(name="GOstats", 
                                    geneSetCollection=gene_annotations, 
                                    geneIds = ensembl_gene_ids, 
                                    universeGeneIds = NULL,  
                                    ontology = "BP", 
                                    pvalueCutoff = cutoff,  
                                    conditional = FALSE, 
                                    testDirection = "over")
```

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘geneIdType’ for signature ‘"character"’

```
str(ensembl_gene_ids)
```

chr [1:3] "ENSG00000100592" "ENSG00000101336" "ENSG00000134285"

```
class(ensembl_gene_ids)
```

[1] "character"

Comment: What is the output for `str(gene_annotations)` and `str(GOstats)`? Do you get the same error when you run the example here: https://github.com/hyphaltip/genome-scripts/blob/master/R-gists/compGOStats.R ?

Comment: sorry, my work environment had changed. I will try tomorrow again, but chances are I will not stumble upon those exact same objects. thank you for the cue , i think we could have found the answer. Ensembl has got some connectivity issues at the moment, but I will try again later.

Comment: If you try again and run into the same problem, post your question to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ (in my experience you have a better chance of getting a solution there)

Comment: Ok, I tried again and I think I fixed the data input, but I am now getting bugged again, by a different issue - 
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘geneIdType’ for signature ‘"character"’. All this, while it actually suppose to be character. None of the solutions worked so far, I think I will try asking at a bioinf junction. Feel free to close this as resolved or post another suggestions if any.

Comment: Okay, thank you every1. With a duplicate answer from Stack Overflow, I was able to succeed a bit only to stumble upon a different issue, for some reason the function `OverMF <- hyperGTest(params2). Error in getUniverseHelper(probes, datPkg, entrezIds) : 
  After filtering, there are no valid IDs that can be used as the Gene universe.
  Check input values to confirm they are the same type as the central ID used by your annotation package.
  For chip packages, this will still mean the central GENE identifier used by the package (NOT the probe IDs).`